# Unity android Ignore collision between gameObjects drag and drop

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to drag a `gameObject` on to another(2D game), to drag and drop objects I use this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Dragger : MonoBehaviour
{
    float tempZAxis;
    public SpriteRenderer selection;
    void Start()
    {
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Touch[] touch = Input.touches;
        for (int i = 0; i < touch.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector2 ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray, Vector2.zero, 100f, (1 << 8 | 1 << 9 | 1 << 10 | 1 << 11));
            switch (touch[i].phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    if (hit)
                    {
                        selection = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                        if (selection != null)
                        {
                            tempZAxis = selection.transform.position.z;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    Vector3 tempVec = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch[i].position);
                    tempVec.z = tempZAxis;
                    if (selection != null)
                    {
                        selection.transform.position = tempVec;
                    }
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    selection = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I had to attach `BoxCollider2D` to each `gameObject` in order to use `RaycastHit2D` and now when I drag object1 to object2, it pushes object2 when they are colliding. I have 4 layers to the `gameObjects`, I tried to call         `Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 10);` on a script attached to the main camera (runs on startup) but it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the interaction between the layers in the Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics menu.

Another option can be (if you don't want your objects to be affected by the physical interactions) to check all the constraints (freeze position and freeze rotation) in all dimensions (x, y and z) in the Rigidbody attached to the objects.

Comment: Thanks, I disabled it in the Physics menu